# How do I list all files a given grunt task depends on for a Makefile?

Tags: node.js, makefile, gruntjs

As [Grunt doesn't support only rebuilding what has changed](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/866), I'd like to wrap a Makefile around it, to just compute the set of "input" files and not invoke grunt at all, unless any of them have changed since last build.

Can you tell grunt to just list what files a given task would depend on on stdout somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [jsoverson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18649282/1130377), I managed to cobble together a proof-of-concept that defers dependency tracking to the Gruntfile, so I can add `Makefile` rules that invoke the grunt bits to build the project. This project uses coffee-script (use http://js2coffee.org/ to convert to js if you want to reuse this for some non-coffee project), so in my `Gruntfile.coffee` I added

```
gruntGetPaths = (fn) -> ->
  taskConfig = grunt.config @args.join '.'
  grunt.task.normalizeMultiTaskFiles(taskConfig)
    .forEach fn ? (files) ->
      files.src.forEach (path) ->
        console.log path

grunt.registerTask 'src', gruntGetPaths
grunt.registerTask 'dst', gruntGetPaths (files) -> console.log files.dest
```

giving me the `grunt src:...` and `grunt dst:...` rules that produce grunt-junk-wrapped file lists.

It seems the junk is guaranteed to be colorized / adds a trailing empty line (at least with `grunt v0.4.1` / `grunt-cli v0.1.9`), so chopping that off by piping their output to `egrep -v '\e|^$'` worked.

Near the top of my `Makefile` I added some macros for that:

```
define GRUNT
    $(shell grunt --no-write $1 | egrep -v '\e|^$$')
endef
define SRC
    $(call GRUNT,src:$1)
endef
define DST
    $(call GRUNT,dst:$1)
endef
```

...and then rules that borrow knowledge from the `Gruntfile`:

```
$(call DST,stylus:compile): coffee $(call SRC,stylus:compile)
    grunt stylus

$(call DST,coffee:glob_to_multiple): coffee $(call SRC,coffee:glob_to_multiple)
    grunt coffee

$(call DST,uglify:my_target): coffee $(call SRC,uglify:my_target)
    grunt uglify

coffee:
    npm install 2>&1 | tee $@
```

...which has corresponding setup looking like this:

```
  @initConfig
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON "package.json"

    stylus:
      compile:
        options:
          paths: ["src/stylus/"]
          import: ["nib"]
        files:
          "stylesheets/foo.css": "src/stylus/foo.styl"
          "stylesheets/foo-dev.css": ["src/stylus/foo.styl", "src/stylus/foo-dev.styl"]

    coffee:
      glob_to_multiple:
        expand: true
        cwd: 'src/coffee/'
        src: ['*.coffee']
        dest: 'javascripts/'
        ext: '.js'

    uglify:
      my_target:
        files:
          "javascripts/foo.min.js": ["javascripts/foo.js"]
```

This works, but is slow. Given a bare `grunt stylus` run that takes 2.94s to run, running these make rules to regenerate css takes another 5.41s of pure overhead, which is sort of horrible - and if I nuke all the generated files and try to regenerate the min.js, there is no dependency resolution as the glob rules can't be traced back to find all intermediate files.

So while it's possible to do this, it did not end up being a solution to the problem "running grunt is slow and stupid, when no source files have changed", as running `grunt stylus coffee uglify` in this project takes 3.25 seconds to reproduce what was already there, and a bare `make` run that just resolves dependencies and finds nothing relevant changed takes over five.

It would of course be great if `grunt` had its own dependency management to know when it can exit immediately, like our grandfather's tools would. :-)

Answer (score 5):

You could do this with a custom task though it would still be wrapped by normal grunt output.

```
grunt.registerTask('src', function(){
  var taskConfig = grunt.config(this.args.join('.'));
  var expanded = grunt.task.normalizeMultiTaskFiles(taskConfig);
  expanded.forEach(function(files){
    files.src.forEach(function(file) {
      console.log(file);
    });
  });
});
```

Command line syntax to list all files for, say, a subtask for jshint called "myFiles" would be `grunt src:jshint:myFiles`

```
$ grunt src:jshint:myFiles
Running "src:jshint:myFiles" (src) task
file1.js
file2.js
dir/file3.js

Done, without errors.
```

Comment: Thanks – combined with the assumption that grunt's own output only adds always-colorful and empty lines, I managed to cobble together my proof-of-concept. I think I'll abandon the experiment; it got slow.